# how to execute a string in angular js directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dynamically building a string which is given below

```
scope.gridOptions = {columnDefs : [ {
    field : username,
    displayName :USERNAME
} ]};
```

and storing in a string myvalue.

My requirement is that compiler has to execute this but it is treating as a string. So please suggest me how to execute a string in angular js

Comment: code shown is an object, how are you converting to string? `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` should work. Really not clear what goals are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse

scope.gridOptions = JSON.parse(yourString);

Comment: tried this getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHeight' of undefined

Comment: @user2609542 your error probably came from diffrent place outerHeight is jQuery/jQLite function.

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear what you meant by saying "executing string".

First, when i saw the title i thought of JavaScript `eval` function ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp))

Afterwards, when i read the question, it seems you are looking to convert from/to a JSON ([what is JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON))

some suggested to use `JSON.parse`. i recommend you not to use it **in your angular code**

alternative to `JSON.parse`:

- `angular.fromJson` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)
- `angular.toJson` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)